# ring video door bell pro 2 blows the ring hard wired transformer but works fine with plug in power adapter

Tags: wiring, transformer, doorbell

My ring video door bell pro 2 blows the ring hard wired transformer (
120V AC 60 Hz power input with 16V 30VA power output) but works fine with plug in power adapter. This happened thrice. Can any one think of any reason behind this ? I dont have any mechanical chime/doorbell involved in the circuit. The transformer is connected directly to the main (120volt) and output of transformer is connected directly to video door bell. It works for the first 5 mins or so and then transformer does not produce any output.

Answer (score 2):

The specs for the Ring doorbell transformer are:

[image]

Instructions for the Ring Video Doorbell Pro 2 indicate that a "Pro Power Kit" must be installed at the chime.

[image]
[image]

I don't know if the Pro Power Kit is needed *only* if you have a chime.

If your wiring from doorbell transformer to doorbell is pre-existing, it may have too high resistance or a short. Old traditional doorbells often used super skinny wire.  Disconnect the wires at both the transformer and doorbell ends, and test for continuity between them (should not be present). Then, twist them together at one end, and measure the resistance of the loop at the other end using a multimeter (should hopefully be low). You may need to run a new higher gauge cable with 20 or 18 gauge wires, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding Pro Power Kit in the circuit. Pro Power Kit is needed even if the chime is not connected. Also I found out that plugin adapter has in-built short circuit protection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It looks like you have 2 accounts. A moderator can merge your accounts and then you could remove this answer and Accept the answer from Armand, which references the Pro Power Kit.